# split or slice a single expect/telnet session into two parts in Python/TCL

Tags: python, tcl, telnet, expect

When we use concept of Multi Thread we will open two telnet session to connect UUT.

What i am thinking is instead of opening two telnet sessions can we use single telnet session split into two halfs, like a big room splitted by walls. Will this possible with Python or TCL languages?

Thanks
Malli

Comment: You mean you want to multiplex two sessions on the same telnet connection? And you want to do that without a custom telnetd or some application-level server-side multiplexer between telnetd and the shell? If so, no, you can't. It's easiest to just multiplex at the socket level (two tcp connections--or I guess you could tunnel two virtual tcp connections over one sctp or quik running over udp or something) or the app level (similar to using screen in an interactive session), but you can do it as a tunnel at the telnet level if you really want to write that code on each side.

Comment: You could use a [threading.Lock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) so that only one thread can access the session at a time. In the big room metaphor, it would be like a bouncer at the door that only lets one person in at a time.

Comment: @abarnet could you explain tunnel mechanism in python/tcl

Comment: @Malli, please explain the problem you are trying to solve. What is the downside of using two telnet sessions?

Comment: You shouldn't need multiple threads to run two telnet sessions; everything's I/O-bound so one thread can service both with a little intelligence in your programming.

Comment: @Donal Could please explain how to do I/O-Bound?